# How to explain why a particular logical statement is false?

Tags: logic

I've been trying to determine an explanation for the falsity of a logical statement for some time now and I've had no luck in figuring out exactly how to go about it. The statement in question goes as follows:

```
Explain why the statement
for any integers a, b, c, if ab = ac, then b = c
is false.
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the way to determine the falsity of a logical statement? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One counter-example disproves a statement: a=0, b=1, c=2.

How do you spot the counter-example?!

Comment: So would I just show that there is a counter example that proves the statement is false and leave it at that?

Comment: A single counterexample is enough to show a statement like this is untrue.